# Package org.springframework.cloud.netflix.sidecar does not exist

Tags: java, python, spring, cloud

I want to use sidecar to call flask with spring cloud, but when I import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.sidecar, hint does not exist.

I guess it's because there's no jar package for sidecar.But I don't know which jar package to use.

Who can help me?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Need to include :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar/2.1.0.RELEASE